# Why is firebase deploying my nextjs app to both firebase hosting and functions?

Tags: firebase, next.js, deployment, firebase-hosting

I have nextjs app and deployed to firebase. i used the experimental feature by firebase to deploy my nextjs.

firebase deployed my nextjs app to both hosting and function, I can click on both links and access the app.

what is the point of firebase deploying to both? why not deploy to one?

you can follow these steps to reproduce:

- create nextjs app npx create-next-app@latest
- enable firebase experiments:enable webframeworks
- firebase init hosting then firebase deploy

I was expecting firebase to deploy to firebase hosting and use functions for api routes, image component, getserversideprops and etc.

Answer (score 3):

Firebase Hosting on its own can only serve static resources. It does not execute your code on its servers.

To allow running your code server-side it uses Cloud Functions.

So when you deploy your Next.js app with `firebase deploy`, it puts any static resources on Firebase Hosting, puts the server-side dynamic code in Cloud Functions, and then configures rewriting rules to tie the two together under your web site URL.

This usually means that there's no need to access the Cloud Functions URL directly, but instead let Firebase Hosting handle that for you.